# Google region restriction

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-places-api

I'm using google places autocomplete module in my angular app and would like to restrict my customer to choose places only within Delhi NCR region. I was able to drill him down to country wise restriction(India) and have tried using location latlng, radius parameters to restrict him to NCR however I'm still getting places suggestions from throughout India in the drop down.

Am I missing something here. Please help me out.

Comment: `and have tried using location latlng, radius parameters to restrict` - perhaps you did this wrong, if you show what you did, someone may be able to show where you did it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Places autocomplete allows restrict search by country as you mentioned in the question.

Location and radius parameters are not strict filters, they just bias the results, but you can get predictions outside the circle.

There is a feature request in the public issue tracker for more strict filters, however at the moment Google doesn't expose any ETA for that.

You can visit and star the feature request in the issue tracker to express your interest and receive updates in the future:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4433